# prove that the product of a vector $\vec a$ and the transpose of a vector $\vec b$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with rank $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need your help in solving this question.

> Given two vectors $\vec a$ and$\vec b$, prove that:
>
> The product of a vector $\vec a$ and the transpose of a vector $\vec b$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with rank $1$.

I can get the $n\times n$ matrix part of the question, but how to prove that $\operatorname{rank}=1$?

Comment: What are the dimensions of a product of matrices? What are the dimensions of a vector? What is the rank of a matrix? Answer these questions and things should be clear

Comment: Do You know matrix product and transpose of a vector like $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$?

Comment: It could be a matrix of rank zero, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be non-zero column vectors with $\mathbf{b}=(b_1, \dots, b_n)^T$. Then, by the definition of matrix multiplication,
$$
\mathbf{ab}^T = (\mathbf{a}b_1, \mathbf{a}b_2, \dots, \mathbf{a}b_n),
$$
which is an $n \times n$ matrix if $\mathbf{a}$ has $n$ elements. Each column is linearly dependent on each other column since they are all just constants multiplying the vector $\mathbf{a}$. Thus, the rank of the resulting product is 1.

Comment: Sometimes the quickest way to get the Question clarified by the OP is to jump in with an Answer.  I'm not sure it will work out here, but your work may at least help future Readers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two column vectors of length $n$. So the transpose $y^T$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix, and $A:=xy^T$ is the product of an $n \times 1$ matrix and a $1 \times n$ matrix and is equal to an $n \times n$ matrix.  We will show that the rank of $A$ is 1 (assuming $x$ and $y$ are nonzero vectors).  Observe that the $ij$th entry of $A$, denoted by $a_{ij}$ is equal to $x_i y_j$. The $i$th row of $A$ is equal to the vector $x_i y^T$ obtained by multiplying the row vector $y^T$ by the scalar $x_i$.  So, $A$ is of the form $A = \left( \begin{array}{c} x_1 y^T \\ \vdots \\ x_n y^T \end{array} \right)$.  Since each row of $A$ is a scalar multiple of the first row, the rank of $A$ (defined as the maximum number of linearly independent rows of $A$) is at most 1. It is equal to 1 if $x$ and $y$ are nonzero (and equal to 0 otherwise).